# Drop-down menu in form with options from database with conditions? Rails 2.3.15

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm writing a piece of an app that allows you to upload photos and assign them to a **Bus**. What I want is a drop-down menu with all the **Name** values. Buses can be either enabled or not. I'd like to restrict the list to just enabled buses. But I'm not sure how to do it in a form as a drop down menu.

This is all I know how to do:

```
    <% Bus.find(:all, :conditions => {:is_enabled => 1).each do |bus| %>
      <%= bus.name %>
    <% end %>
```

But I don't know how to put this code in a form without it breaking in a variety of different ways, and I don't know any other way to get these names. This app uses an older version (Rails 2.3.15).

This was my best guess on how to do it:

```
<% form_for @bus_image, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| -%>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

    <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :name %><br />
       <% Bus.find(:all, :conditions => {:is_enabled => 1}).each do |bus| %>
       <%= select(bus.name) %>
       <% end %>
     <div>

<% end -%>
```

... which gives me `wrong number of arguments (1 for 3)`.

Thanks, let me know if you need/want any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
f.select(:bus_id, Bus.find(:all, :conditions => {:is_enabled => 1}).map{|b| [ b.name, b.id ] }, {:include_blank => true })
```

In place of :

```
   <% Bus.find(:all, :conditions => {:is_enabled => 1}).each do |bus| %>
   <%= select(bus.name) %>
   <% end %>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Well, there's a new error (which is exciting :)!) that returns "undefined method `merge'".

Comment: f.select(:bus_id, Bus.find(:all, :conditions => {:is_enabled => 1}).map{|b| [ b.name, b.id ] }, { :include_blank => true })

I think map will work :